# NO VPN- import Ipvansish

Tags: release-juno, vpn

Whats going wrong with elementary OS 5 Juno ? There is NO way to import IPvanish- vpn's. This option (import VPN-connection) works in other Linux-distros without troubles. Why NOT in elementary ? Somebody an idea or an answer ? Is this a intention ? Special thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: - Solution / import IPVanish VPNs:

after importing the vpn, --> you need the **CA-certificate** (ca.ipvanish.com.crt) - and it works  :-)

... what a fool I am   ;-)